# how to set component attribute value in static resource css

Tags: lightning-aura-components, static-resources, dynamic, style

**problem :**
I have to set values of css dynamically . I upload css file in static resource

**css is like :**

```
  p {
     font-size : {v.font_size}
  }
```

**component :**

```
<aura:attribute name="font_size" type="string" default ="30px">
```

how can i set this attribute value in static resource css when including this static resource in component ... Is it possible to do that .. if not then how to
assign values dynamically in static resource

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem to be right way of applying the styles.

Usual and recommended path is to define style classes in static resources, use them in component, then dynamically apply classes in the HTML markup.